# Automatically add new sheet to formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet which calculates the total numbers for whole year. I plan to create separated sheets for each month.

How can I make the Year sheet, so its calculations would automatically count the new sheet?

Example:
1. January - I've got general sheet/tab called YEAR 2016 and another called JAN. 
2. February - at the end of February I create sheet called FEB. I want YEAR 2016 to sum positions in these two sheets by automatically expanding formulas range.

Preferably without VBA.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Create-a-3-D-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-40ca91ff-9dcb-4ad1-99d2-787d0bc888b6

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the job:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(JAN!A1; 0); IFERROR(FEB!A1; 0); IFERROR(MAR!A1; 0); IFERROR(APR!A1; 0); IFERROR(MAY!A1;0 ); IFERROR(JUN!A1; 0); IFERROR(JUL!A1; 0); IFERROR(AUG!A1; 0); IFERROR(SEP!A1; 0); IFERROR(OCT!A1; 0); IFERROR(NOV!A1; 0); IFERROR(DEC!A1; 0))
```